# Different hosting option with NancyFX?

Tags: c#, hosting, web-hosting, nancy

This may be very basic question. But I was wondering about different nancyfx hosting option. Basically I read an article about hosting Nancyfx web application on heroku, at their they mentioned that self host is necessary for this type of hosting. Normally I bootstrap my project with Nancy asp.net hosting and its works pretty well. But still I want to know more about hosting options that Nancyfx provides. Basically what is the difference and where I can use which one???

Even few good links will be great help.

Please let me know if any further details needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Nancy documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Documentation) has a section on hosting which is a good place to start. It has sections on hosting Nancy apps on ASP.NET, WCF, Azure, Umbraco and self hosting.

As an aside I can mention that I've run Nancy on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) simply by using Nancy ASP.NET hosting and pushing that through Git to AppHarbor. No complications.